# How to reduce the size of swap file from 3.8 GB to 1GB?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, swap, swap-file

I'm using Jetson TX2 L4T v28.3 but I can't seem to find the swap file in L4T OS 28.3 (UBUNTU Bionic 18.04). I tried to locate it via `grep` but the file can't be located.

```
jetpack4-2@jetpack42-desktop:~$ cat /proc/swaps 
Filename                                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/zram0                              partition   670720  4436    5
/dev/zram1                              partition   670720  4384    5
/dev/zram2                              partition   670720  4404    5
/dev/zram3                              partition   670720  4384    5
/dev/zram4                              partition   670720  4384    5
/dev/zram5                              partition   670720  4388    5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just want to get some more free space, right? If yes then you're doing the wrong way. Your PC is using [zram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zram), **not** swap file, so **no space is wasted on disk**. To free up some ***disk space*** see [No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?](https://askubuntu.com/q/911865/253474)

---

Shrinking zram size is also not a good idea when you have no backing swap file or swap partition and you'll get into trouble when your system is low on memory. If you use the [`zram-config` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zram-config) then by default upon installation it'll create one zram drive for each CPU core, with total size being `<total amount of RAM>/2`. You can find the setting (for each drive) in `/usr/bin/init-zram-swapping` as `mem=$(((totalmem / 2 / ${NRDEVICES}) * 1024))`. However that's the maximum drive size and not the size consumed on RAM. The actual zram drive content is compressed to just a fraction of the used size. So just leave the zram drives as-is

---

In case you really need to do a resize then you must modify `/usr/bin/init-zram-swapping` if you're using `zram-config`, or if zram was created manually then run the following commands with root permission to change the size of zram0

```bash
swapoff /dev/zram0
zramctl --reset /dev/zram0
zramctl --find --size 1024M # or echo 1024M > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
mkswap /dev/zram0
swapon /dev/zram0
```

Do the same for zramX, or write a simple script for that. For more information zramctl read [its manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/zramctl.8.html)